# Compass Extension equivalent of config.rb

Tags: sass, compass-sass

At the end of my Compass `config.rb` I have a little snippet that generates a random number. This works. And I can get it working when I have the snippet there and the Sass in my projects Sass folder.

I'm trying to create an extension out of this functionality, But I don't know where to put the code so that my mixins in `extensions/my-extension/stylesheets/`, and hopefully any Sass file that imports the extension have access to it.

I've tried `extensions/my-extension/lib/whatever.rb` but I'm still getting errors. I've also tried putting the snippet in `config.rb`, but keeping the mixins/Sass in the extension, but that also doesn't work.

In both of these cases the error I'm getting is that `Undefined operation: "random() times 1%".)`

Where is the place analogous to the end of the `config.rb`, but for extensions?
Do I need to import it into my extensions' Sass somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/), particularly the subsection of "Advanced Layout Options" entitled "Library File Location". It lists three different options:

> 1. `my_extension/compass_init.rb`
> 2. `my_extension/lib/my_extension.rb` (NOTE: You must use this one if you're distributing as a rubygem.)
> 3. `my_extension/my_extension.rb`

Adding your random number function to any of these files should work.